# How to know which cities Google Street View are available?

Tags: search, google-maps, street-view

Google just released Street View for some cities in my country. Are there some way to find out if a city is available on Street View? Is there a list of cities or a search tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find this information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Street_View#Areas_included

Answer (score 1):

This question on Google's support pages - [In which parts of the world is Street View available?](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=68384) has a map showing current coverage.

A full page map can be found [here](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/streetview_landing/streetview-map.html)

Comment: A bare link isn't that useful. Can you extract the relevant information and include it here - keeping the link for reference

Comment: @Patrice: I added more information on question to clarify what I need. The map doesn't help too much.